# Custom tSpeedButton painting

Tags: firemonkey, custom-painting

I have two `TSpeedButton` buttons on a form. When one button is enabled, the other is disabled and vice versa. I want to paint the buttons with custom colors to reflect whether they are enabled or disabled.

I coded a procedure named `SetButtonsColors`. This procedure sets (one button at a time), the variables `ButtonFillColor` and `ButtonStrokeColor` with the custom colors, accordingly with the button state, and immediately commands the repainting of the button.

On `ButtonPaint` handler I set the `Canvas.Fill.Color` and `Canvas.Stroke.Color` with `ButtonFillColor` and `ButtonStrokeColor` respectively and do the filling and drawing of the `aRect`.

For my disappointment, the buttons are always painted with the colors set for the last button. This happens, I presume, because `Windows` paints the buttons asynchronous, and hence, uses the last settings for `Canvas.Fill.Color` and `Canvas.Stroke.Color`.

If this is true, how can I force `Windows` to paint the button immediately after it's repainting is commanded?

Follows the code for `SetButtonsColors` and `ButtonPaint`:

```
procedure tForm1.SetButtonsColors;
begin
  if Button1.Enabled then begin
     ButtonFillColor   := tAlphaColorRec.White;
     ButtonStrokeColor := tAlphaColorRec.Black;
     Button1.Repaint;
     ButtonFillColor   := tAlphaColorRec.Black;
     ButtonStrokeColor := tAlphaColorRec.White;
     Button1.Repaint;
  end;
  else begin
         ButtonFillColor   := tAlphaColorRec.Black;
         ButtonStrokeColor := tAlphaColorRec.White;
         Button1.Repaint;
         ButtonFillColor   := tAlphaColorRec.White;
         ButtonStrokeColor := tAlphaColorRec.Black;
         Button2.Repaint;
       end;
end;

procedure tForm1.ButtonPaint (Sender: tObject; Canvas: tCanvas; const aRect: tRectF);
begin
  Canvas.BeginScene;
  Canvas.Fill  .Color := lvButtonFillColor;
  Canvas.Stroke.Color := lvButtonStrokeColor;
  Canvas.FillRect (aRect, 0, 0,  []       , 1, CornerTypeBevel);
  Canvas.DrawRect (aRect, 0, 0, AllCorners, 1, CornerTypeBevel);
  Canvas.EndScene;
end;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your code does not compile ;) Anyway, you are doing it wrong. Just test the (Sender as TButton).Enabled in the paint handler. But your diagnosis seems correct. Of course the buttons are repainted as needed and when possible, so using common variables like you did cannot really work.

Comment: @Frazz. Thanks. I already suspected that I should have separate variables for each button. I was just seeking for a confirmation or, conversely, if was any other way to force Windows to paint the buttons immediately after the `Repaint` command.

Comment: You don't NEED separate variables for each button because each button already has its Enabled property. Use that and it will all be much simpler ;)

Comment: I made my own ´ButtonPaint´ procedure as:


            Fill  .Color := tAlphaColorRec.red;
            Stroke.Color := tAlphaColorRec.Blue;
            FillRect (ARect, 0, 0, []        , 1, TCornerType.Bevel);
            DrawRect (ARect, 0, 0, AllCorners, 1, TCornerType.Bevel);

but the ´Stroke´ painting has no effect. Notthing is painted. Any suggestions / ideias?

Comment: Sorry folks. I assume that Stroke.Kind was automatically Solid. Problem solved. Please ignore comment above.